# Issue with log4j2's event from one test class being registered on next test

Tags: java, multithreading, log4j2, junit4, completable-future

I'm facing a problem with Log4j2 on two integration tests (junit4) (a batch app that calls multiple end-points using CompletableFuture.ofAll) run by FailSafe. I would like some thoughts from you.

The he first test being run is aimed to fail and it is logging the errors properly. The second test is aimed to pass and using a different endpoint.

The problem is that, somehow, I'm seeing errors from the first test (a timeout from a worker-thread) being registered on log4j after the second test have started. And as we build the app's exit code from the number of errors registered on our Appender class, this is affecting the assertion on this exit code in the second test.

Our appender is being reset by our launcher class on every app's start already. so this is not the problem.

I've changed the order of execution of the tests using **<failsafe.runOrder>reversealphabetical</failsafe.runOrder>** and this was enough to both pass green.

But I would like to know if there are anything that could be done on Failsafe or Log4j or even in my app to prevent this.

Comment: are you sure all CompletableFutures are finished before you start the second test? They are async

Comment: Well, I'm using allOf(), so I was expecting that all was finished before the second test to start. But seems that there is one that was not finished.

Do you know if exists anything I can do to ensure that ?

Comment: just answered, hope it solves it